# Exponential random variable X with a uniform random variable as its parameter

Tags: probability, random-variable, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution, exponential-distribution

$$X\ \sim Exp(U) ~ and\ U\ \sim  U(0,1) $$

The question asked for the value of $ P(X\geqslant 1)$

I saw the solution and it went like this:

$$P(X\geqslant 1) = E[P(X\geqslant 1)|U] = E[e^{-u}] = \int_{0}^{1}e^{-x}dx  $$

Could someone explain the solution to me?

More specifically how did the solution derive each step?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are given that the conditional distribution of $X$ given $U=u$ is $\text{Exp}(u)$ (presumably $u$ is the rate parameter), where $U$ itself is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.

The solution is an application of the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), or equivalently, the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Suppose $I(X\ge 1)$ is an indicator variable that equals $1$ if $X\ge 1$ and equals $0$ otherwise. And let the density of $U$ be $f_U$. Then,

\begin{align}
P(X\ge 1)&=E\left[I(X\ge 1)\right]
\\&=E\left[E\left[I(X\ge 1\mid U\right]\right]
\\&=E\left[P(X\ge 1\mid U)\right]
\\&=E\left[e^{-U}\right]
\\&=\int e^{-x}f_U(x)\,dx
\\&=\int_0^1 e^{-x}\,dx
\end{align}

In the penultimate step, [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician) was used to find the expectation.

Comment: Yes I think I understand this better now.

Would it be equally accurate if I wrote it this way? P(X≥1) =∫P(X≥1|U)fu(u) du = E[P(X≥1∣U)]

Comment: You can directly say $P(X\ge 1)=\int P(X\ge 1\mid U=x)f_U(x)\,dx$ by law of total probability.